# How to prevent typing negative values in extjs number field

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Here I'm using ExtJS 5.1.2.

I have to prevent entering negative values in number field.
By using '0' value for "minValue" property 'Down' key and mouse wheel are not allowing negative values.

But User is able to type negative values into the field.

Is there any config to prevent entering negative value to number field ?

**Example Code:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.field.MyNUmber', {
    extend:'Ext.form.field.Number',
    xtype: 'myNumberField',
    fieldLabel: 'My NUmmber',  
    allowBlank: true,
    allowDecimals: true,
    decimalPrecision: 2,
    minValue: 0,
    step: 0.25
});
```

Comment: Any example of code we could help you with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, I've used [`allowExponential: false`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number-cfg-allowExponential)... [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14re).  I realize it's not really meant for this (and it could possibly be a bug), but it seems to do the trick... note if you take off `minValue: 0`, then you can enter negative numbers.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'On The Wall',
            width: 300,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                anchor: '100%',
                name: 'bottles',
                fieldLabel: 'Bottles of Beer',
                value: 99,
                maxValue: 99,
                minValue: 0,
                allowExponential: false,
                allowDecimals: true
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Take one down, pass it around',
                handler: function() {
                    this.up('form').down('[name=bottles]').spinDown();
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but you could set a listener on the number field and change the value of the field in the event the entered value is less than 0:

```
 listeners: {
     change: function(field, value) {
         value = parseInt(value, 10);
         if (value < 0) {
             field.setValue(0);
         }
     }
 }
```

[Sample fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14lv)